# ¿Puede usarse el subjuntivo optativo o yusivo en oraciones principales?

Tags: subjuntivo

Ya sé que el subjuntivo se puede usar en oraciones principales con “todavía” o “quizás,” o cuando el verbo principal es “poder,” “querer” o “deber.” ¿Pero se puede usar el subjuntivo optativo o yusivo en oraciones principales? Por ejemplo: “¡Viva España!” o “corra el juicio como las aguas.” En uso ordinario, ¿se usa el subjuntivo así, sin “que” antes de la cláusula, con un significado optativo o yusivo?

Comment: El subjuntivo se ve frecuentemente en frases solemnes, como por ejemplo "Hágase la luz" (referencia bíblica).

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Gracias por el comentario y el ejemplo! Ya había supuesto que este uso ocurre frecuentemente en uso religioso, pero mi cuestión específicamente pregunta si es encontrado en uso cotidiano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí y en castellano se llama el subjuntivo *exhortativo*.

Hoy en día es menos común que antes porque se suele usar introducido con *que*. En estos casos, hay una cláusula principal implícita, haciendo de la con el subjuntivo una cláusula subordinada. Pero no hay ninguna razón de no usarlo propiamente en la cláusula ordinal, solo que puede sonar un poco anticuado a menos que sea para usar como un imperativo con Vd./Vds./nosotros/nosotras.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el uso corriente es en oraciones subjuntivas. Sin embargo, en[El subjuntivo en Español](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/) se puede encontrar una explicación más extensa y con más matiz:

> El subjuntivo expresa una actitud de la persona con respecto a alguien
>   o algo. Por lo general, necesita de otro verbo que determina el
>   significado de esa actitud. Se utiliza con frecuencia en oraciones
>   subordinadas que empiezan con la palabra QUE, pero no todas las
>   oraciones con QUE necesitan del subjuntivo. **Se utiliza también en la
>   forma imperativa (excepto con tú afirmativo).**

Puedes encontrar un listado de usos en [¿Cuáles son los usos del subjuntivo?](http://www.elsubjuntivo.com/usos.html) de la misma página.